# Reset and form is not visible after confirmation message in WPForms

Tags: wordpress, wpforms

I am using WPForms in my wordpress website for the contact page. I followed the tutorial which is available in the [WPForms](https://wpforms.com/developers/how-to-display-the-confirmation-and-the-form-again-after-submission/). But when i submit the form i am getting the confirmation message but my form gets disappeared.

I tried to modify the snippet but nothing is working, i couldn't able to find any solutions regarding this issue.

Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: could you please share website url ?

Comment: https://www.fresharapicklz.com/